# What is this image stored as?

Tags: html

I want to extract these telephone numbers from the website, either as an image or if possible as a string.

Here is an example from the website: [Link](http://www.callmyname.sg/view/Rexy+Employment+Ag/Uk9JRC9TRzA0SkstOTZDRERFNTEuMjQyNS9DRkMzLThDNTktNDg=)

As you can see the telephone number is an image.

However I cant seem to view the image when I open the image source:

`<img src="http://www.callmyname.sg/search/display_phone_number/VUhkVE1WOW5BV1lFWWxSbVhUdFRObGMzQlRBRU9nPT0=">`

But when put into html and viewed in a browser, you can see the image fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 1):

It's a solution to prevent people like you from scraping their website :)

The url `http://www.callmyname.sg/search/display_phone_number/VUhkVE1WOW5BV1lFWWxSbVhUdFRObGMzQlRBRU9nPT0=` leads to a script that generates the image - probably based on the argument.

```
VUhkVE1WOW5BV1lFWWxSbVhUdFRObGMzQlRBRU9nPT0=
```

Since it ends with an equals sign, I tried to decode it as base64:

```
UHdTMV9nAWYEYlRmXTtTNlc3BTAEOg==
```

Now it looks even more like base64, so I tried another round:

```
PwS1_gfbTf];S6W70:
```

So it's clearly not plaintext (or not encoded with base64), which would be ridiculous and would let you extract the number this way. They either use some special cipher, or store the numbers in database with this as identifier.

I don't think you can steal the phone number easily, only using OCR perhaps.

---

When you visit the URL, you will get garbage, since they do not send proper MIME header

```
�PNG  IHDR�,���tRNS���7X}4IDATx���_HZo�g�� E��p��l��EHTx!]�DtQ�M�.x3��.dx�*b]Dl"]�D���bQq.B����Z2$��:ȡ�wq��9�s���Cx>W�}���ٳ��ڶ����]���Ǐ�/_���ݿ���ahh���\q����������555�=���*�"�*�*�f�����}uu�e�d2���o����?00p����J%ȴds���BB�˲�`�`0RJy����n�{cc�e�H$b�ۻ����(�~�_����A4�Z��_�V|��J�w�����t:��333.��ƕ������+^����L`���֑��W��3�X�"    y���$p'U"��F���y���z&�ioo��萟�*� ����\�L&Sx����p�e���ׯ_R��y�J%�~����|qq��|e�Z%:�J�{��q��nW�ՉD"�J��~�n4��������̔Ty���qF���>BwGa�z����������8��ߡc�f��B�>!�Ub�N�s���|�F�^/B���Lj��i��NfJ��͛D"����� o!t��`����fvv�eم��V���D)�����x���d2966&�n� ^,0O4��(!D��l�h46�-�~��Tً>B�"�Q�>,�P��ok@U \�BU,�P���=G SA+GIEND�B`�
```

but it's really just ordinary PNG image:

[img http://www.callmyname.sg/search/display_phone_number/VUhkVU5scGlBV1lDWWdFelVEUUhZQWRvQlRZR013PT0=](http://www.callmyname.sg/search/display_phone_number/VUhkVU5scGlBV1lDWWdFelVEUUhZQWRvQlRZR013PT0=)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a png-file, generated by a computer before being displayed. You can reference it fine from any other page though, and you should also be able to download it easily (right click, save as ...) *Note: I tested this, make sure you save the image with the extension `.png` and not `.html` which it will default to.*

```html
<img src="http://www.callmyname.sg/search/display_phone_number/QkNOVE1RODNBV1lDWWdVM1V6ZFZNZ1JyRFQ0Rk1BPT0=">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a PNG image, but the server doesn't specify the right content header. It tells your browser that is't an html page in UTF-8 encoding, so you just see some garbage (including the letters PNG at the start).

The `<img>` tag though doesn't know how to display text so it just tries to load it as an image (and with success).

I don't see a way to extract the numbers in any other way than just reading the image. Because it contains only numbers and will have a similar format all the time, maybe you can find a simple way to parse it instead of using a full fledged OCR library.